# Froala: custom HTML template for images

Tags: javascript, html, froala

This is the default HTML Froala produces for images:

```
<p>
 <span class="fr-img-caption fr-fic fr-dib" style="width: 300px; width: 300px;">
    <span class="fr-img-wrap">
      <img src="..."><span class="fr-inner">Image caption</span>
    </span>
 </span>
</p>
```

What if I want to change this HTML structure to something like

```
<figure>
    <img src="..." alt="">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

So the image size, caption text and additional attributes may stay the same but the surrounding HTML tags are changed.

HTML code for image is hard-coded in image.min.js that comes with Froala, so the ideal solution would be to have an option to specify a html template for images, but since Froala does not provide it in the current version - I am looking for other options, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am thinking about the following options:

1) unminify `image.min.js` and change the HTML there, but that will break future updates of Froala

2) catch `froalaEditor.image.loaded` event and update image HTML with jquery using `replaceWith`

3) update entire Froala HTML by replacing image with my code upon form submit

Comment: Did you manage to achieve that?

Comment: No, unfortunately

Comment: Also looking a solution for this. Froala still using spans in 2020